# Force Alt+Tab show only active desktop apps in gnome-shell

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome

I'm using Gnome Shell.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> shows all opened application windows from all virtual desktops. It becomes impossible to use when many windows are opened. Is it possible to show only these apps which are on active desktop?

Comment: Try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/464946/ubuntu-gnome-force-alt-tab-to-only-switch-on-current-workspace

:)

Answer (score 11):

There is a Gnome Shell extension that does this: [Alt Tab Workspace](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/310/alt-tab-workspace/).

You could also directly enable this behavior in the default switcher by running:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only true
```

which is what the extension does under the hood.

Comment: This answer reserves higher consideration. As it solves OPs problem with out an extension. I just checked it and found working in Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 .

Comment: But it also removes grouping of similar apps. That is if two terminals are open they are shown differently. I think it is not a problem.

Answer (score 7):

One potential option you may wish to consider is the [Gnome-Shell Alternate Tab extension](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Extensions/alternate-tab)

It is the traditional Window-based Alt-Tab switcher that Ubuntu users have grown up with.

- Windows are not grouped by application, nor by workspace
- Thumbnails show window previews
- Windows are sorted by time of focus

It doesnt meet your question "active desktop" criteria - however it does make switching more obvious and easier when you have multiple windows opened.

It is [packaged in a PPA](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/gnome_shell?dist=natty)

**To Install**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testing 
sudo apt-get update
sudo gnome-shell-extensions-alternate-tab
```

As with all PPAs - these are testing for testing purposes.  Either have a full backup you can restore with or use `ppa-purge` to remove the PPA

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ricotz/testing
```

Answer (score 4):

## You don't need any extension to enable this behaviour.

`dconf-editor` provides this feature as an option:

```
$ sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Then

```
$ dconf-editor
```

This launch an graphical interface of system configuration database.

Navigate into it to `org > gnome > shell > app-switcher` and then, check the `current-workspace-only` checkbox option.

Close `dconf` window and try `Alt+Tab`. It should work as expected now.

Answer (score 3):

Two ways to solve the problem.

1. Install a plugin which modifies the behaviour of Alt+Tab to conventional methode. Then it shows all the opened windows go http://fpmurphy.com/gnome-shell-extensions You will find the plugin.
2. The current <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> feature is good. You try to understand it in a different way. let me explain. your <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will show opened applications. if you have more than one window opened for a same applicaiton then use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> to switch between windows. It will automatically select the desktop. to change application use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and to change window of same applicaiton <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> that is great way.

Comment: 1) I can't see any plugin providing the required functionality on the web you have linked. 2) It's not great, I have been trying to get used to it for several months now, and finally concluded that I don't like it at all. I want to tab just through the windows local to the current virtual desktop.

Comment: @salva - have you tried the alternate tab extension (http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Extensions/alternate-tab) - its much better than standard alt-tab i.e. sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-alternate-tab from this PPA (http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/gnome_shell?dist=natty)

Comment: @fossfreedom: thanks! write a new answer so I can award you the bounty!

Comment: @salva - have written an answer...

Comment: re 2: I don't get it. In my opinion if I opened 2 different Terminal windows in 2 separate workspaces it was for a reason. It's because I group my activities by workspaces. For example, in first workspace I compile something using Eclipse + Terminal, in second I opened it to do a quick 'find | sed'. In my opinion Alt-Tab must switch those 2 instances of Terminal as separate application