# Force alt + tab to switch only on current workspace in GNOME shell

Tags: shortcut-keys, workspaces, gnome-shell, application-switcher

I am looking for a clean and fast method to force GNOME in Ubuntu 14.04 to switch between active apps only on the current workspace when pressing the shortcut <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with:

Very fast & easy, without any installations/extensions:

1. Install `dconf-editor` (already installed on current debian/ubuntu distributions):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
   ```
2. Open `dconf-editor` (from the Dash or a Terminal)
3. Navigate to: org -> gnome -> shell -> app-switcher
4. Set "current-workspace-only" to true

   [image: screenshot]

..and you're done :)

Comment: Wish Gnome would just put this in their Settings applet

Comment: Please add @austinmarton answer too, since while this is more generic, there's a gnome way that requires no extra installs.

Comment: I've added feature issue to Gnome TWEAK project https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-tweaks/issues/123

Comment: Wish this will become the default for future release!

Comment: This should be on Gnome Tweak! Agree @sobi3ch

Comment: As of Ubuntu 18.04 this setting can be found at /org/gnome/shell/window-switcher/current-workspace-only

Comment: @GuruBob I've got both of these settings available in dconf in 18.04, however the shell/app-switcher one listed in the answer was the one that I needed to change.

Comment: WARNING: For me in Ubuntu 18.04 does not work, but the command line version worked: gsettings set org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only true

Comment: As of Debian 12, Bookworm, you can change this via Settings > Multitasking and see Application Switching at the bottom.

Answer (score 320):

Simply:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only true
```

Comment: super fast, no extra software necessary and does exactly what was asked for! +1

Comment: This isn't working for me on Ubuntu 16.04. I think it might be due to these settings being managed in several different apps. Any idea how to make this setting overrule the others?

Comment: It worked for me on Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: ...and for me in 17.10.

Comment: It's working on Ubuntu 18.04. 
It's straightforward and you don't need to install anything

Comment: Strangely, it doesn't work for me in 18.04, but this extension does: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/310/alt-tab-workspace/

Comment: Nice. How can I set this as a default for all users.

Comment: @crafter see [How can I change default settings for new users?](https://askubuntu.com/q/65900/301745)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Works on Ubuntu 18.04. thank you, thank you, thank you!!!

Comment: If it doesn't work, you can try replacing `gsettings` with the fully qualified `/usr/bin/gsettings`. Package managers like Anaconda can muck with the default `gsettings` alias.

Comment: Works on 20.04 as well.

Comment: Does not work for me on 18.04.

Comment: Does anybody know if this is possible but for screens? I.e. alt tab between stuff on the screen I am currently interacting with, but not other screens. I like to have one screen with a fixed set of tools (email, slack etc) and then my main screen for active work, but alt tab will select slack or email rather than switching between two tools I am using on my primary screen

Comment: This worked for me on 21.10.

Comment: Does this only work for "Switch Applications" or also for "Switch Windows"?

Comment: Still working! awesome

Answer (score 26):

Seems to be fixed with

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.window-switcher current-workspace-only true
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only true
```

Comment: Looks like I need only the first one (`.window-switcher`)

Comment: This did the job. It only shows the apps currently in the workspace and, when an app has two instance each in a different workspace when pressing Alt+Tab it prevents from showing both of them. But you have to use both the commands in this answer. Awesome, thank you!

Comment: Debian Buster : the first line did it for me.

Answer (score 22):

As an alternative to installing `dconf-editor` and having to fiddle around with your mouse so much, you can also do this from terminal.

To create the `current-workspace-only` value:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/app-switcher/current-workspace-only 'true'
```

To erase it, going back to default settings:

```
dconf reset /org/gnome/shell/app-switcher/current-workspace-only
```

I would like `dconf-editor` more if it could search through paths, properties, and values.

Comment: the [(later) answer using `gsettings`](https://askubuntu.com/a/759740/17060) is just a higher-level api that also sets the `dconf` values (and would probably be in general preferred over directly accessing dconf)

Comment: This solution work still on Ubuntu 21.10. Perfect.

Comment: For keys that don't exist yet, dconf does not let you auto complete them, while gsettings does. f.e. `dconf write /org/gnome/shell/app-sw` then pressing tab does not complete to anything, but `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.app-sw` then pressing tab completes to `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.app-switcher`

Answer (score 14):

An alternative for people who want to tab through open windows on current workspace but also want to be able to tab through all open apps (on any workspace) this can be achieved by changing the keyboard shortcuts.

Under Settings > Devices > Keyboard (on Ubuntu 17.10):

- Switch Windows: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Switch Applications: <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

Comment: That's tricky - Alt+Tab changes windows, even when changing the keyboard shortcuts. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Yes, Alt+Tab will show the windows open on the current workspace whereas Super+Tab will show all open programs (on any workspace). What do you want to achieve, that Alt+Tab shows open programs on the current workspace instead of open windows?

Comment: Hi ! I'm trying to set this specific behavior, but I don't seem to be able to. Both commands always behave the same. I tried gsettings current-workspace-only for window and app switcher with no luck either. Any idea? Thanks :)

Comment: I checked my gsettings and I have `org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only false` and `org.gnome.shell.window-switcher current-workspace-only true`

Comment: This does not answer the question but is a great tip nonetheless.

Comment: This is great, thanks! Just did this in Ubuntu 18.04 and it's really helpful. It seems I didn't have Alt+Tab bound to anything originally (but it still performed the 'switch applications' action). After binding Alt+Tab to 'switch windows', I had to re-bind Super+Tab to 'switch applications' for some reason.

Answer (score 8):

### [AlternateTab](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/15/alternatetab/)

If you *also* want to [ungroup applications on switcher](https://askubuntu.com/a/1106528/349837) you can add the officially supported [AlternateTab extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/15/alternatetab/).

[image: screenshot]

[Moreover](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106481/can-i-configure-gnome-to-show-open-windows-on-the-dock-individually/1106528#comment1825618_1106528):

> Actually, Ubuntu is going to have the Alternatetab as default on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> in the upcoming version of Ubuntu (19.04), while the current default app switcher will remain on <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

The other solutions here did not work for me on Ubuntu 18.04.1, but the [Alt Tab Workspace](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/310/alt-tab-workspace/) extension worked.

Comment: That's odd. If you follow [the code](https://github.com/kwalo/gnome-shell-alt-tab-workspace/blob/master/alt-tab-workspace%40kwalo.net/extension.js#L12) it does the same as [austinmarton's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/759740/349837)