# Isolated/independent workspaces

Tags: gnome-shell, workspaces, application-switcher

Is it possible to make Ubuntu 18.04 workspaces independent from each other? I mean, when I'm in workspace 2 and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, I don't want to switch to workspace 1 and see Firefox. Instead, I want it to search in the same workspace (2) and switch to the related app (let's say a Terminal).

I was using Xubuntu before and it was the default behavior but It seems Ubuntu doesn't offer such option as far as I'm aware.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force alt + tab to switch only on current workspace in GNOME shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464946/force-alt-tab-to-switch-only-on-current-workspace-in-gnome-shell), just run the following command in Terminal: `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only true`

Comment: @pomsky yes that's my problem. and your solution worked. thanks.