# Prevent Alt + Tab from showing active windows in other workspaces (GNOME)

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, workspaces, application-switcher

Is it possible to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between active windows in the current workspace only?

The default behaviour shows active windows across all workspaces, effectively allowing me to switch workspaces using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, something I would like to prevent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force alt + tab to switch only on current workspace in GNOME shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464946/force-alt-tab-to-switch-only-on-current-workspace-in-gnome-shell), simplest solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/759740/480481

Comment: thanks! this wasn't suggested to me in my search at all for some reason :/