# How to make alt+backtick switch only windows on the current workspace?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, workspaces, application-switcher

There are multiple questions and answers about how to make <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switch only applications of current workspace, most notably [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464946/force-alt-tab-to-switch-only-on-current-workspace-in-gnome-shell).

However, is there any way to enforce the same behavior to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (or <kbd>~</kbd>, simply the key above <kbd>Tab</kbd>), which is for switching windows of current application?

Answer (score 4):

In Ubuntu 20.04, to do what you want, I had to set both:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only true
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.window-switcher current-workspace-only true
```

(the first is non-default in 20.04).
You can do this from the command line, or by installing `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor` then running `dconf-editor` (see [detailed guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464946/force-alt-tab-to-switch-only-on-current-workspace-in-gnome-shell))

I found that the reload button in dconf-editor wasn't sufficient - I had to reboot (perhaps re-login would have been sufficient?).

With the defaults (window-switcher current-workspace only, but app-switcher not), <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> gives the contrary behaviour where the app-switcher is confined to the current workspace but the window-switcher within each app is not. So, for example, if you have browser windows open in other workspaces, you will have to cycle through them all. Setting the app-switcher to current-workspace-only should limit both to the current workspace.

According to the [19.04 release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DiscoDingo/ReleaseNotes), <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> was changed from app-switcher to window-switcher. So, from 19.04 onwards (only tested in 20.04), I suggest you use <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> and/or <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>. You can hold down the <kbd>Super</kbd> while tapping either of the other keys in order to cycle through apps and/or windows (see [switching between windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-windows-switching.html.en)).

<kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> gives the same contrary behaviour unless you confine both the app-switcher and the window-switcher to current-workspace-only.

Note: <kbd>Super</kbd> is the Windows key and <kbd>`</kbd> will often be whatever key is above <kbd>Tab</kbd>, whether or not it is labelled with a backtick or grave accent.