# When a press alt+tab or super+tab, can it juste show some applications?

Tags: shortcut-keys, application-switcher

When I press alt+tab or super+tab to switch  application, I find it annoying that there are too many applications(like spotify, signal, discord, ...) running on my computer but I check them roughly once a day but there are necessary for the message notification. Therefore, I'm wondering that is there a way that it only shows applications I want (like terminal, firefox and document reader) when I press alt+tab or super+tab?

Comment: You can separate workspaces for alt-tab, so you just put everything you don't need regularly on a different workspace. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/464946/force-alt-tab-to-switch-only-on-current-workspace-in-gnome-shell

Comment: I didn't use workspace so I don't know that. However it is a great solution!!! Thank you a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force alt + tab to switch only on current workspace in GNOME shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464946/force-alt-tab-to-switch-only-on-current-workspace-in-gnome-shell)